# How i can get the last id of INSERT query when i'm using an external php file for doing all type of querys?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How i can get the last id of INSERT query when i'm using an external php file for doing all type of querys?
I have this class in php:

```
class DBManager
{
    private $db;
    private $queryResult;

    public static function getInsetance()
    {
        static $inst = null;
        if ($inst === null) {
            $inst = new DBManager();
        }
        return $inst;
    }

    private function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'mydb');
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo 'DB CONNECTION ERROR';
            die;
        } else {
            mysqli_query($this->db, 'SET NAMES UTF8');

        }
    }

    public function _destruct()
    {
        mysqli_close($this->db);
    }

    /**
     * @param $query
     * @return bool|mysqli_result
     */
    public function runQuery($query)
    {
        return $this->queryResult = mysqli_query($this->db, $query);
    }

    /**
     * @return mysql_result
     */
    public function getLastQueryResult()
    {
        return $this->queryResult;
    }
}
```

And in another file, I want to do some different query. I want to get the last id of INSERT query in this code:

```
session_start();
require 'DBManager.php';

$db = DBManager::getInsetance();



    $query = "INSERT INTO `test`(`creator`, `name`) VALUES 
             ('$creatorid','$name')";

    $result = $db->runQuery($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
$last_id = $db->insert_id;
```

[Source](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_lastid.asp)

Comment: Yes.I Have. But I don't know how and where i must use this!

Answer (score 0):

I found:

In  DBManager class i must do this changs:

```
   public function runQuery($query)
    {
        $this->queryResult = mysqli_query($this->db, $query);
        $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($this->db);
        if($last_id !== 0){
            return   $last_id;
        }

        return $this->queryResult;

    }
```

and i will get $result in server file.